# JavaScript document.links is broken

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Here is the code:

```
console.log(234, document.links);
console.log(235, document.links.length);
```

The output shows that there are values in the array, yet it returns 0.

[image]

[image]

This is the latest version of Google Chrome. Could it be the fact that this is running inside of an iframe?

Comment: is this question edited ? when i run it in console it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a comma instead of a period...

```
console.log(234, document.links);
console.log(235, document.links.length);
```

Comment: That was just a typo when typing the question.